# how to force bash interpreter?

Tags: bash, shell

I have two simple shell scripts to run my solr installation in a screen and restart it on crash (sometimes a memory heap exception happens...)

startserver.sh

```
cd apache-solr/example
screen -S solrserver ./runner.sh
cd ../..
```

runner.sh

```
until java -jar -Xmx1024m start.jar; do
    echo "server stopped with exit code $? restart..." >&2
    sleep 10
done
```

they work just fine so far, the problem however is, that runner.sh must be executeable for the current user.

so this has to explicitly set.

i have everything in subversion, and subversion is not intelligent enough to manage access rights.

so i am looking for a solution to start the script not as executeable script in the current environment but rather pass it on to the interpreter.

something like:

```
/bin/bash runner.sh
```

another alias for that should be just `. runner.sh` (well than its not  necessarily bash but the current users shell)
i did this with perl and php scripts before but somehow it won't work

i have a straight forward ubuntu 10.04 lts server on an amazon instance. well i installed apache2 and some apache modules, subversion and my favorite command line editor but no major system adaptations.

---

it works very well with `/bin/bash` i must have gotten something else wrong. sorry.

Comment: it works very well with /bin/bash i must have gotten something else wrong. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [svn:executable](http://www.mernin.com/blog/2008/02/making-scripts-executable-inside-subversion/) property

Comment: i whish there was something like svn:writeable as well, but it doesnt look like it

Comment: set your umask to 002 or even 000 - might do the trick.

Comment: thanks for that hint. but i am afraid it wont be possible as this would affect everything and not special files/folders. and its also hard to maintain because i am not the only one working with that svn and i would have to explain it to everybody etc. i am considering switching to git

Answer (score 2):

have you a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) at the beginning of your script ?

This way, when you launch your script, the shell will know what to do, in your case, use `bash` to launch the script.

Add `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of your script (first line).

Comment: thats true and important, but in this case my problemw as that the shell refused to launch at all. in fact i had a shebang, and i wanted to launch it over an interpreter. leveraging the necessarity of a shebang as a side effect